# How do I kill all active connections on OSX?

Tags: macos, port

This problem has bugged me for a very long time. Say, I start servers at ports 55555, 55556, 55557 and 55558. I have debugged the server enough, so I kill the processes with ctrl+z. However, it doesn't kill the connections and I get 'address already in use' error when I try starting them again. I can always close the terminals to actually kill the connections or I could run these commands for each terminal:

```
lsof -i :<port>
kill -9 <pid>
```

Both ways are way too time consuming when I have to have about 5 servers open to debug a program I'm working on. Is there a 'find and kill all active ports' command?

Comment: ‘*kill the processes with ctrl+z*’ There's your problem. Ctrl+z doesn't *kill*, it *suspends*. Try Ctrl+c.

Comment: Oh wow, I've been using the wrong command for the past forever. Now I feel dumb...